# Synonymous tags: [correspondence-chess], [correspondence]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

(Didn't find a dedicated thread for tag synonyms.)

I suggest [correspondence-chess](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/correspondence-chess) as a a parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ed synonymized the tags under [correspondence-chess](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/correspondence-chess).